# Wrong instance billing on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

**I have 4 reserved instances with a few months left:**
c1.medium (active)
m1.small (active)
m1.small (active)
t1.micro (active)

**In "My Instances" i see 5 stopped instances, and 4 running:**
m1.small
m1.small
m1.large
c1.medium

**In the billing section, it's clear that i am billed for the running instances:**

*Amazon EC2 running Windows Reserved Instances:*
c1.medium (17 hrs)
m1.small (1270 hrs)
*Amazon EC2 running Windows:*
m1.large (640 hrs)
c1.medium (665 hrs)

Problem is, i can't seem to move the working machines to the reserved instances (it suggests only "on demand" and "spot" instances...)

**what is the best approach for utilizing the already paid for (and cheaper) reserved instances?

How do i do that?**

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Comment: Amazon offer free support around billing. Ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Your instances should automatically take advantage of reserve if there are reserves available.

However, you have to remember that reserve [comes with a number of limitations](http://theagileadmin.com/2011/03/31/why-amazon-reserve-instances-torment-me/) - when you buy reserve they are locked to

1. Instance type
2. Availability zone and region
3. Operating system

If your instances are in a different AZ, for example, from what you bought, they won't take advantage of reserve pricing.

Comment: Thanks - but should i do now? shall i shut down a server, and the next time i create an instance it'l use the reserved one?

Comment: @seldary correct, if you bring it up in the right size/type/az.  You can actually change instance types with a stop and start now, but I think have to terminate/create to move AZs.

Answer (score 0):

Reserved instances are still on-demand instances, they have an hourly charge. That hourly charge is just cheaper than for a non-reserved on-demand instance.

Comment: Thanks - i know, but i am paying a higher hourly rate for an on-demand instance, while a cheaper reserved instance is lying around doing nothing...